# How to declare two jobs with different Docker images in gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

Is there a way to run two jobs using two different Docker images?

I've tried to run this configuration but without any success:

```
before_script:
   - docker info

build:default:
  image: ubuntu:latest
  script:
    - pip3 install -r requirements.txt
    - [..]

build:docker:
  image: docker:latest
  script:
    - docker build -t app .
    - docker run -d -p 8000:8000 --rm app:latest
    - [..]
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? e.g. by giving details on the error log (and more generally on the unexpected behavior you observe)?

Comment: Your configuration looks correct. As the previous commenter said, please share more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by others in the comments the config file was fine, the problem was with gitlab runner itself.
So i made the following changes:

- Change `volume` value to `volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]` into `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`
- Add `variables:
         DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay` 
  to your Dockerfile.